# Gradle tomcatRun and eclipse-wtp are using not processed files

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a problem with tasks like tomcatRun, or running application with wtp-plugin. The problem is that both tasks are using not processed webapps, and wtp is using even not processed resources, and we are replacing tokens on processResources and war task depending on profile.

I was thinking on two different solutions:

1. Change dependencies of those tasks to be run after mentioned before, and change sourcefolders for them to use the generated ones
2. Instead of replacing tokens we would replace whole files during processing with the profiled versions. By default the file would be filled with data for some profile. We could create some task to set those files in source folders as well.

Neither of them looks to be a clean one, so is there some better way to do this? Are there some gradle specific guidelines on dealing with profiles?

Comment: If you want to use a WAR file for deploying to Tomcat, you can use the task `tomcatRunWar` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we will want to run it without building war on local environment. We will probably just go with the solution of keeping some default settings in files and replacing whole files on processing resources. Not the cleanest way, but if nobody will find another then it's not much of a choice:)